# Where are binaries of a program running inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I've deployed a container based on ubuntu:16.04

```
docker run -ti ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

I 've downloaded from apt nsnake , inside the /bin/Bash in the container, a game:

```
apt install nsnake
```

and I have not such game on my host.

Now I wanna know where nsnake's binaries are ***on host machine***;
         on host machine :

```
ps -e | grep nsnake
```

and then , taking PID:

```
file /proc/PID/exe
```

but **instead of returning the file pointed from /proc/PID/exe** , this last command gives me :

```
/proc/PID/exe: broken symbolic link to /usr/games/nsnake
```

So , the important question is :
is there a method to find the location of binaries of nsnake ?

Other interesting questions are :

- why symlink is "broken " ?
- if there is no reference to original bins inside the related /proc/PID/exe , how do the system know what code it has to run ?

Answer (score 2):

> Q. why symlink is "broken " ?

You are mixing the main pid namespace with the container's pid namespace. It is broken in your host, but it is not broken from the container's point of view.

> PID namespace provides separation of processes. The PID Namespace removes the view of the system processes, and allows process ids to be reused including pid 1.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Do the same that you are doing in your host, but do it inside the container. You will see that the `pid` (process id) of `nsnake` is a different number. Inside your container the symbolic link is not broken:

```
# docker exec -it <container-id> file /proc/231/exe
/proc/231/exe: symbolic link to /usr/games/nsnake
```

(you will need to install file utility inside the container, `apt-get install file`, or just do `ls -l /proc/PID/exe`)

Docs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces#Process_ID_.28pid.29

> Q. if there is no reference to original bins inside the related /proc/PID/exe , how do the system know what code it has to run ?

The process that is running containerized (in your example `/bin/bash`) sees its own filesystem that is mounted by docker for you:

```
# Inside the container
root@d0fb6fdea3b5:/# mount
overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/4FPUTTI4XND27BPHH7FS4JKJ4V:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/U65SX2N4JGA5X6TXGRJQERQWNX:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/OEX7NG4TZRGXBBFSSQ7Q3FXC5R:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/FXRLO27CABA4ZFNOFTOL2HFHP4:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/KBEK646A7PRLHLWM6CVJRMXSEH:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/PSRBIMSE36LW2MZEOSMM3XDG2Y,upperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b867408de3a3915bc5f257aecaf73193083b3c8cc84c5d642810a3eaaeef550/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b867408de3a3915bc5f257aecaf73193083b3c8cc84c5d642810a3eaaeef550/work)
...
```

In this case the storage driver is ["overlay2"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/). The Linux Kernel receives from `/bin/bash` process the system call that asks for a fork execution of `/usr/games/nsnake` and as it's expected, it will look for that binary in the filesystem that the container process can see.

Comment: Ok , maybe  the question is unclear on this ... the point is I want to reach bins location looking "through" host's PID hierarchy , not through hte new namespace's PID tree . I need the "very absolute" path of the executable bins ,  the path on host machine.

Comment: You are entering in the docker internals. There is no direct path in your host. Docker uses layered storage that is not so easy to inspect from your host. That also depends on what storage driver your docker setup uses: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/.

Comment: There's also the mount namespace, akin to a chroot.  The path is mostly useless from the host.  You may find it with `sudo find /var/lib/docker -name nsnake -type f`